# Uncertainty relation proof from Sakurai

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

could someone please help with the proof of this,it's from JJ Sakurai book modern quantum mechanics

[image: HUP]

Comment: Help in what way?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24116/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/230041/2451 and links therein.