# What exactly the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle explains?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I just don't understand what Heisenberg meant by the statement that "It is impossible to determine both position and momentum of an electron simultaneously.If one quantity is known then the determination of the other quantity will become impossible." Now, it obvious that position of an object can not be determined if it is in motion or having a momentum because it is continuously changing its position. If it is at rest we can determine its position but not momentum since it has a zero velocity. Did he mean that electron never come to rest?

Comment: Yes, to your last question, the electron is never fully at rest, it always has what's called zero point energy. For an electron to have no kinetic energy, it has to be at absolute zero temperature, which is impossible for us to achieve. Have a look at http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/229168/ and look at all  the answers.

Comment: An electron is not an object. It's a quantum, so all this means is that exchange of charge between two systems is not localizable in a classical phase space.