# Can two simultaneous independent measurements circumvent uncertainty?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, observers

Without understanding the mathematics, I have learned that  the uncertainty principle precludes being able to precisely measure the position and velocity of a particle at the same time.
So my question is, would two different people be able to measure a particle at the same time, one measuring the velocity and the other the position. And so by sharing their results be able to circumvent the uncertainty principle?

Comment: Given the uncertainty principle the idea of "at the same time" surely doesn't work.

Comment: There are no known ways of taking a measurement that doesn't involve changing something about the particle's relations (whether that be its position or velocity). Simultaneous measurement of both properties would simply change and destroy the results for both measurements (when the objective was to change neither).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncertainty principle and multiple observers](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75475/)

Comment: @Steve: *There are no known ways of taking a measurement that doesn't involve changing something about the particle's relations (whether that be its position or velocity)* Not true in general. If you know in advance that you have a pure state, then measuring which state it is has no effect on the wavefunction.

Comment: @BenCrowell, isn't that just shifting the problem around (by requiring advance knowledge, which therefore has to be measured in advance but without actually impacting the system)?

Comment: In 2016, an experiment was finally realized in which two non-commuting observables were measured at the same time! The Heisenberg uncertainty principle is *not* violated because as you learn more about one observable, you learn less about the other. The experiment was done with superconducting circuits. [Here's the arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.06652)

Comment: @DanielSank, but isn't that the point: you can't measure both variables precisely at the same time?

Comment: @Steve the old fashioned idea that you measure an observable instantaneously doesn't work. We have to respect the fact that acquiring information takes time. With that in mind, you can acquire information on two observables simultaneously, and the resulting physics is interesting!

Comment: @DanielSank, what does "simultaneous" mean for something that cannot be instantaneous? Or maybe, again, does it not just shift the problem around, by posing the challenge of how two non-instantaneous-measurement-processes are perfectly aligned in time? Clearly, if you process-measure two things over two different time ranges, then the properties being measured have the chance to change slightly between the ending of one measurement and the ending of the other?

Comment: @Steve could you take a look at the paper I linked, and then perhaps we can discuss in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar). I don't want to try to discuss quantum measurement theory in comments.

Comment: Your error is in thinking that uncertainty is a technical limitation that we have. It is not. Uncertainty is a fundamental property of nature, like it or not. You can't measure two values at once not because you *can't*, but because they don't exist at the same time. They are two sides of the same medal. Can you see two sides of the same medal at once (no "mirrors" please).

Comment: @safesphere, the problem with that analogy is that it is all-too-intuitive that you *can* observe both sides of a medal, by hook or by crook, unless arbitrary constraints are introduced that rob the analogy of any explanatory power. Fundamental particles don't appear to have well-defined edges - asking where they are is more akin to asking of a rainbow "where *exactly* does yellow end and green begin?", or of the solar system "where *exactly* is the border?". That's not a complete analogy of the subatomic situation, but it contains an insight that has to be carried forward.

Answer (score 1):

No matter how many people take measures, the object under study is the same for all of them. So you can't avoid the indetermination principle.

Answer (score 0):

I ask that you learn the mathematics. It is not too hard! You don't even need to understand all of the bra/ket formalism or the Schrödinger equation, just the de Broglie relation is enough.

Waves have a size scale at which they interfere, which we call their "wavelength," and de Broglie correctly predicted that for matter this would go inversely as the momentum, $\lambda=h/p$. The whole quantum theory is about matter being made of these probability waves with these sizes. But there is an intrinsic uncertainty between the position of a wave and its wavelength: if you know its position really well  then you know it fits into a very small box, say of size $\Delta x$. But if you know its wavelength very well then you must be able to observe it for many wavelengths, and that means it must be spread out over space.

With a bit of reasoning you can come to this idea: that for any waves there should be an intrinsic fractional uncertainty in wavelength $\lambda$ which goes inversely with the count of wavelengths that fit in the box, $\Delta x/\lambda$. We would write this as $$
\Delta\lambda/\lambda \ge \alpha \lambda/\Delta x.$$With some mathematics due to a man named Fourier we can determine what this constant $\alpha$ must be, and with some mathematics due to a man named Leibniz we can see this pattern of  uncertainty $\Delta \lambda/\lambda^2$ as an uncertainty in the reciprocal $\Delta(1/\lambda),$ which de Broglie's relation tells us is $h^{-1}~\Delta p$ because $h$ is a constant.

So to answer your question whether  two people can measure both simultaneously: No, they will get in each other's way because one is trying to see if the particle is in a small box, and the other is trying to measure the number of wavelengths that fit into that box, but as they want to measure precisely enough to violate the uncertainty principle, the first researcher has a maximum size constraint while the second has a minimum size constraint for the same box.

Answer (score -1):

When you measure something, a limit in the uncertainty you have is how well defined is the quantity you want to measure. Example: the position of a table with 1 meter of width, will have a inevitable error of 1 meter in the direction of it's width, because the table isn't a point with infinitelly well defined position. Well, when two variables don't conmute and heissemberg's uncertainity tell's you that the product of the error of both quantities is, at least, a given magnitude, tour trouble with the inevitable error on the measurement is in the object itself (the table width), not in the way you are trying to measure. If you smash the table and you cut it in tiny pieces, you will have a smaller error with the position of every bit of what ago was a table, but you aren't trying anymore to measure the table's position, because it doesn't exist anymore. Also, if you are trying to measure the position of a part of the table when it isn't broken, that's a different measurement, it isn't the table position.

Good look.